# Outlook 365 addin throws 401 unauthorized error on android outlook mobile app

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

I am developing Outlook Add-In that will run over all modern browsers, android and iOS.

I am using Managed EWS API to fetch the email and its attachment by passing `ewsUrl`, `itemId` and `ewsToken` in `OAuthCredentials` class which is my remote service.

I am getting `ewsToken` by using `Office.js getCallbackTokenAsync` method from UI and passing all this information to my remote service to use the Managed EWS API to fetch email from exchange server.

For browsers it works fine but when we use Outlook Mobile on Android, `ewsUrl` returns `null` which I hard-coded to `https://outlook.office365.com/ews/exchange.asmx` but now I am getting `401 unauthorized` error.

How can I identify if `ewsToken` or `itemId` is wrong?

Comment: It fails even for the hard-coded URL, because `getCallbackTokenAsync()` on iOS/Android returns REST-compatible token even when the `isRest` parameter is not specified (see [this discussion](https://github.com/OfficeDev/outlook-add-in-command-demo/issues/29#issuecomment-356002208))

Answer (score 1):

Per the [documentation](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/outlook/1.4/Office.context.mailbox), EWS functions are not supported by Outlook for Android or Outlook for iOS. This includes `ewsUrl`, `convertToEwsId` and other methods related to calling into EWS.

I recommend visiting the [UserVoice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/) and adding your suggestion.