# Outlook AddIn Mobile Issue - not working in mobile whereas same code works for Desktop and web client

Tags: outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I have the bellow error in Microsoft exchange server service, but only on mobiles as same code works for Desktops and web.

ERROR MESSAGE:

> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401)
>   Unauthorized.
>
> at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() at
>   Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EwsHttpWebRequest.Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.IEwsHttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
>   in
>   \REDMOND\EXCHANGE\BUILD\E15\15.00.0913.015\SOURCES\sources\dev\EwsManagedApi\src\EwsManagedApi\Core\EwsHttpWebRequest.cs:line
>   113 at
>
> Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestBase.GetEwsHttpWebResponse(IEwsHttpWebRequest
>   request) in
>   \REDMOND\EXCHANGE\BUILD\E15\15.00.0913.015\SOURCES\sources\dev\EwsManagedApi\src\EwsManagedApi\Core\Requests\ServiceRequestBase.cs:
>   line 821The request failed.
>
> The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.

CODE SNIPPET:

```
// Create an ExchangeService object, set the credentials and the EWS URL.
ExchangeService exchangeService = new ExchangeService();
exchangeService.Credentials = new OAuthCredentials(attachmentToken);
exchangeService.Url = new Uri(ewsUrl);
exchangeService.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
exchangeService.PreAuthenticate = true;
try
{
var getAttachmentsResponse =exchangeService.GetAttachments(attachmentIds.ToArray(),null,new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties,ItemSchema.MimeContent));
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
var errMsg = ex.Message;
var errInnerException = ex.InnerException;
message += "Inner Exception :" + errInnerException;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Outlook 365 addin throws 401 unauthorized error on android outlook mobile app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46804213/outlook-365-addin-throws-401-unauthorized-error-on-android-outlook-mobile-app)

Comment: This issue got resolved, just we need to convert all attachments IDs and token into REST

Regards
Girish